# EXCEL IF function logical test with date/time formats

Tags: excel, function, date, time, formula

I've been working for a project to improve the managing of key performance indexes and I've hit a wall.

Project: To evaluate whether the process(warehouse and quality) meets the deadline. When an Order comes in, the date/time is recorded and depending on the date/time, the deadline is different.

For ease of explanation let B = Order received date/time (FORMAT DD.MM.YYYY HH.MM), X = Deadline (IN SAME FORMAT)

Conditions: 
1. If B is between 5.01 am and 1pm, then X = 5pm, else X = next day 9am
2. If B is between sat 5am to 5am mon, then X = mon 9am.

I have managed to figure out condition 1 but i have no idea how to incorporate condition 2 into my formula.

Current formula

`=IF(AND(B>DATE(YEAR(B),MONTH(B),DAY(B))+5/24,B<=(DATE(YEAR(B),MONTH(B),DAY(B))+13/24)),DATE(YEAR(B),MONTH(B),DAY(B))+17/24,DATE(YEAR(B),MONTH(B),DAY(B))+24/24+9/24)`

I'm hoping the community can give me some insight on how to solve this enigma as i've been having plenty of luck finding solutions here.

Comment: Is your data in Excel formatted as Date/Time or as string?  If it is already as date/Time you can just do math on it by figuring out the decimal value of your time markers and adjusting accordingly.    Like right now it is 4:33pm where I am.  Excel stores this as .69, some quick editing and I find 5 pm is .71.  So to change a date/time to 5pm, just remove the existing decimal and add .71 to it.  make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Answer:

=IF(OR((AND(WEEKDAY(B6)=7,TIME(HOUR(B6),MINUTE(B6),SECOND(B6))>5/24)),WEEKDAY(B6)=1,(AND(WEEKDAY(B6)=2,TIME(HOUR(B6),MINUTE(B6),SECOND(B6))<5/24))),WORKDAY(B6-1,1)+9/24,(IF(AND(B6>DATE(YEAR(B6),MONTH(B6),DAY(B6))+5/24,B6<=(DATE(YEAR(B6),MONTH(B6),DAY(B6))+13/24)),DATE(YEAR(B6),MONTH(B6),DAY(B6))+17/24,(IF(B6<=(DATE(YEAR(B6),MONTH(B6),DAY(B6))+5/24),DATE(YEAR(B6),MONTH(B6),DAY(B6))+9/24, DATE(YEAR(B6),MONTH(B6),DAY(B6))+24/24+9/24)))))

Its lengthy but i'll try my best to explain.
1. The first part is the weekend portion: IF(OR((AND(WEEKDAY(B6)=7,TIME(HOUR(B6),MINUTE(B6),SECOND(B6))>5/24)),WEEKDAY(B6)=1,(AND(WEEKDAY(B6)=2,TIME(HOUR(B6),MINUTE(B6),SECOND(B6))<5/24))),WORKDAY(B6-1,1)+9/24

IF SAT>5am OR SUN OR MON <5am, VALUE IF TRUE = Next workday 9am (mon)

VALUE IF FALSE = (IF(AND(B6>DATE(YEAR(B6),MONTH(B6),DAY(B6))+5/24,B6<=(DATE(YEAR(B6),MONTH(B6),DAY(B6))+13/24)),DATE(YEAR(B6),MONTH(B6),DAY(B6))+17/24,(IF(B6<=(DATE(YEAR(B6),MONTH(B6),DAY(B6))+5/24),DATE(YEAR(B6),MONTH(B6),DAY(B6))+9/24, DATE(YEAR(B6),MONTH(B6),DAY(B6))+24/24+9/24)))))